# Android Seekbar - How to detect that the slider stops at a particular point more than X milliseconds?

Tags: android, seekbar

My app has a seekbar and inside onProgressChanged I put in my code to process some image.

It all works but because the processing takes a significant amount of time (sometimes 1 second), it is really laggy.

I would like to change it so that when user slides the slidebar, no processing is being done until the slider stops at a particular point for more than 300 milliseconds for example, so that if a user slides very quickly from left to right, no processing will be made.. does this makes sense?

Any suggestions?

Note: I am currently moving the processing into an AsyncTask, even with that, I would still like to only execute the AsyncTask after the slider stops at a certain point, I don't want to start multiple tasks if user slides very quickly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll probably benefit from watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7d-h31BmAg&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc86y1CjAlexivfvOms6_0NC

Comment: Ideal job for a Handler and postDelayed/sendEmptyMessageDelayed

Comment: @Luksprog that video is exactly what my problem is..

Answer (score 0):

Do the processing in `onStopTrackingTouch()`, instead of `onProgressChanged()`.

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        int progress = seekBar.getProgress();

        // Process here, for example using AsyncTask
    }
}
```